# Get is not working PHP

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm working on a Get but I never get any value..
I know the problem is in the .htaccess which looks like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]*)/?([a-zA-Z]*)?/?([a-zA-Z0-9]*)?/?$ index.php?controller=$1&action=$2&id=$3 [NC,L]
```

I don't know which part is creating the problem, the link looks like this: http://royvanoeteren.nl/portfolio/delete?page_ID=21

When I do the $_GET['page_ID'] I don't get 21 but I get no value.

Does anybody know which part of the .htaccess is causing the problem?

I like to hear from you :)

Comment: There is no page_ID located in your rewrite string `index.php?controller=$1&action=$2&id=$3`

Comment: You need the `QSA` flag to add the original query string to the rewritten url: `[QSA,NC,L]`. And using a sequence of optional groups is bound to lead to problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no page_ID located in your rewrite string `index.php?controller=$1&action=$2&id=$3`

That's why, I think ;)

Also you need to add the `QSA` tag to the string (https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html)

Comment: So I make it like this? RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]*)/?([a-zA-Z]*)?/?([a-zA-Z0-9]*)?/?$ index.php?controller=$1&action=$2&id=$3&page_ID=$4 [QSA,NC,L]